# How to set height width of svg icon

Tags: html, css

How to set height width of svg image in html and also I have to use position absolute because I have to set search icon like this image.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMiyY.jpg]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>


        <style type="text/css">


    .form-box{
            display: block;
        padding: 8px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        / box-shadow: none; /
        border: none;
        border: 1px solid #a4a4ac;
    }


        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div>
     search your result

     <svg height="1024" width="973.125" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M960 832L710.875 582.875C746.438 524.812 768 457.156 768 384 768 171.96900000000005 596 0 384 0 171.969 0 0 171.96900000000005 0 384c0 212 171.969 384 384 384 73.156 0 140.812-21.562 198.875-57L832 960c17.5 17.5 46.5 17.375 64 0l64-64C977.5 878.5 977.5 849.5 960 832zM384 640c-141.375 0-256-114.625-256-256s114.625-256 256-256 256 114.625 256 256S525.375 640 384 640z"/></svg>
     <input type="text" name="" class="form-box">
    </div>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Give `viewBox` to svg image and `height` , `width` in css as you want to set svg.

```css
.form-box{
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 28px 8px 8px;       
  border-radius: 5px;      
  border: none;
  border: 1px solid #a4a4ac;
}
.searchwrap p{
  display:block;
}
.searchinput {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.searchwrap svg {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="searchwrap">
  <p>search your result</p>
    <div class="searchinput">
     <svg height="1024" width="973.125" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1024 974"><path d="M960 832L710.875 582.875C746.438 524.812 768 457.156 768 384 768 171.96900000000005 596 0 384 0 171.969 0 0 171.96900000000005 0 384c0 212 171.969 384 384 384 73.156 0 140.812-21.562 198.875-57L832 960c17.5 17.5 46.5 17.375 64 0l64-64C977.5 878.5 977.5 849.5 960 832zM384 640c-141.375 0-256-114.625-256-256s114.625-256 256-256 256 114.625 256 256S525.375 640 384 640z"/></svg>
     <input type="text" name="" class="form-box">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the inline `Height` and `Width` attribute of svg file. You can remove them by opening svg in a text editor.

after that, you can set the `height` and `width` using css like this

```
svg {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add viewBox="0 0 1024 974" and apply class for resize SVG

```css
input{
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 28px 8px 8px;       
  border-radius: 5px;      
  border: none;
  border: 1px solid #a4a4ac;
}
.box {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.box svg {
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
search your result

<div class="box">
     <svg height="1024" width="973.125" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1024 974"><path d="M960 832L710.875 582.875C746.438 524.812 768 457.156 768 384 768 171.96900000000005 596 0 384 0 171.969 0 0 171.96900000000005 0 384c0 212 171.969 384 384 384 73.156 0 140.812-21.562 198.875-57L832 960c17.5 17.5 46.5 17.375 64 0l64-64C977.5 878.5 977.5 849.5 960 832zM384 640c-141.375 0-256-114.625-256-256s114.625-256 256-256 256 114.625 256 256S525.375 640 384 640z"/></svg>
     <input type="text" name="" class="form-box">
    </div>
```